# What is going on with Python OpenGL, PyQt, and Legacy OpenGL compatibility?

Tags: python, qt, opengl

I'm trying to get a handle on what Python OpenGL is doing and Qt usage.  Actual questions in **bold**.  Apologies in advance if there are too many questions for proper SO format, but they are all related and I'm guessing someone who knows the answer to one probably knows the answer to all.

I'm using Python 2.7 with PyQt4, and the Python OpenGL module on Win7 x64.
`GL.glGetString('GL.GL_VERSION')` returns `'3.3.0 - Build 8.15.10.2725'`

So this tells me I'm using a modern version of OpenGL, which by my understanding no longer uses fixed pipeline and the user is required to provide shaders.

1. **Is the version of OpenGL provided by the Python module considered a reasonable modern version?**
2. **Does PyQt4.QtOpenGL provide its own implementation, or does it rely on the Python OpenGL module?**
3. **How can I check the version of OpenGL provided by PyQt4.QtOpenGL, if it is in fact a separate installation?**

However if I don't use the function `GL.glUseProgram(...)`, I can still get some stuff rendered on the screen with basic shading in response to lighting.  So this implies there is some default shader.  I'm not sure if this is part of OpenGL, or just something that is included with the Python module.

4. **Is there a default vertex and fragment shader provided in Python OpenGL module, which is used if I don't call `glUseProgram(...)`, or is this a fixed-pipeline shader provided by compatibility mode?**

On the other hand, I can install my own shader, so this appears consistent with a later version of OpenGL.

Also, the Python Qt4 OpenGL example has extensive use of `glBegin()` and `glEnd()`, with `glVertex`, rotation matrices, etc., tells me this is using legacy OpenGL.

5. **So does this mean the Python OpenGL module enables `GL_ARB_compatibility`?  Or does this possibly come from the PyQt4.QtOpenGL submodule?**

Also, looking at Qt5.5 OpenGL example in C++, there is no call to `glBegin()`, and there are a few shaders included in the example.  I'm guessing this is pure modern OpenGL with no legacy stuff going on.

6. **How can I check the version of OpenGL used by Qt5.5 (C++)?**

I'm also a bit overwhelmed by all the Qt support for OpenGL and I'd like to be able to follow the non-Qt examples from around the web, and to try to use OpenGL-provided structures if possible, rather than QT classes.

For example (copied from HeNe website http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/blending/16001/):

```
#include <gl\gl.h>              // Header File For The OpenGL32 Library
#include <gl\glu.h>             // Header File For The GLu32 Library
#include <gl\glaux.h>           // Header File For The GLaux Library
...
GLfloat xrot;                       // X Rotation
GLfloat yrot;                       // Y Rotation
GLfloat xspeed;                     // X Rotation Speed
GLfloat yspeed;                     // Y Rotation Speed
GLfloat z=-5.0f;                    // Depth Into The Screen
GLfloat LightAmbient[]=  { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };    // Ambient Light Values
GLfloat LightDiffuse[]=  { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };    // Diffuse Light Values
GLfloat LightPosition[]= { 0.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f };    // Light Position
GLuint  filter;                     // Which Filter To Use
GLuint  texture[3];                 // Storage for 3 textures
```

7. **How do I use modern "pure" OpenGL in Qt, without relying so heavily on the Qt classes that don't appear to add that much Qt-specific functionality, eg `QMatrix4x4`, etc?**

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Everything you need to use raw OpenGL using Qt is documented [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglfunctions.html). You'll access any other function set in an identical manner, except that you won't be using `QOpenGLFunctions` as these are for OpenGL ES 2.0, but some other class derived from `QAbstractOpenGLFunctions`.

It was your choice to read about and contemplate using higher-level interfaces. They are there if you wish to use them, but again - it's all your choice whether you do or not. The full, function-resolved OpenGL API is there for you, conveniently provided by Qt, as long as the platform's implementation supports the functionality you need (i.e. provides the version of the interface you requested).

1. Yes. But it's not a version provided by the Python module, it's a version provided by the underlying platform. When the platform doesn't support a particular function, you'll get an exception. Python merely does the function address resolution for you, it doesn't implement any OpenGL per se - it only provides a decent way of using what your platform provides from Python (vs. C).
2. It uses the underlying OpenGL implementation directly - it wouldn't make any sense for it to call into Python, as Python's OpenGL module doesn't do anything besides translating between C and Python.
3. It won't be a separate installation. Both Python and Qt use the same platform implementation, and will call into the same library.

6. Your code must request a particular version in the format you set on a   `QOpenGLContext`, and then, after `create()` succeeds, you can check if you got that version or a lower one. In all cases, it's the context's `format` that supplies the version.

   The functions themselves are available through the `QAbstractOpenGLFunctions` interface, this is as raw as it gets.
7. Qt provides useful convenience classes that add usable interface on top of C data structures - there's nothing impure about them and you're not forced to use them. In fact, they are not available through the basic OpenGL interface. Once you have a context, you use its functions through `versionFunctions`. To make it easy, privately inherit from `QOpenGLFunctions_maj_min`, then `initializeOpenGLFunctions()` once you've made the context current. See the documentation for [`QOpenGLFunctions`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglfunctions.html) for a use example.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  Python OpenGL makes more sense now.  As for QT and using non-QT helper structures, it looks like it boils down to just finding the right header files.